# "Усопшие души" - корректно?

Tags: стилистическая-сочетаемость

***Отпевание усопших душ***

Так можно? На бытовом уровне, о собственно церковных канонах не говорю.
Контекст - репортаж, само событие упоминается вскользь.
Срочно надо.

"Мертвые души" не предлагать - там само сочетание обязано существованием своей абсурдности.

(+)===

**UPD** Вопрос потерял актуальность. Текст опубликован в исходном виде.
Но не закрываю, ибо есть и академический интерес.
И вынужден сказать предметно: ***Вопрос лишь в сочетаемости. Может ли душа - в очевидном по контексту значении - стать усопшей***.

Answer (score 4):

1. Может быть, надо просто посмотреть **в словаре.**

**ДУША,** ж. 1. **По религиозным представлениям:** духовная сущность человека, особая нематериальная бессмертная сила, обитающая в теле человека (иногда животных, растений), покидающая его во время смерти, сна и вновь проявляющаяся после смерти в иной материальной оболочке. Вера в бессмертие души.  **Молиться за упокой души.** Д. с телом расстаётся (человек умирает). Д. отлетела (человек умер). Отдавать Богу душу (умирать).  // **В идеалистической философии и религии:** особая нематериальная субстанция, высшая форма развития единого мирового начала. Д. мира. Мировая д. // **В материалистической философии и психологии**: внутренний мир человека, его самосознание как свойство высокоорганизованной материи.

**УСОПШИЙ,** -ая, -ее. Книжн. Умерший, покойный. У. деятель науки. У-ая принцесса. Поминать усопших родственников. <**Усопший, -его; м.** Читать молитву над усопшим. **Усопшая, -ей; ж.** У. была хорошим человеком.

2. Тогда правильная сочетаемость: **души усопших.** Усопшие души (без натяжек, условностей и переносных значений) – это некорректно.
3. Можно посмотреть сочетаемость в Интернете: [https://kartaslov.ru/сочетаемость-слова/усопший](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9)

На свежих могилах своих приемных родителей ... помолились горячо **за упокой душ усопших** их приемный сын Сабиров вместе с его родной матерью Марией Толстых.

Вероятно, сочетание "усопшая душа" встречается, но смысл выражения неточный.

Comment: *Может быть, надо просто посмотреть в словаре.* Sharon? спасибо, конечно, но, похоже, я не смог правильно сформулировать вопрос... Значение слова "душа" в данном контексте очевидно (=умершие, всего скорее - новопреставленные).  Смотреть тут ничего не надо. Ну и "усопший" тоже без всякого словаря понятно.

Comment: Я еще сочетаемость посмотрела.  Корректно все-таки – это души усопших.

Comment: *Тогда правильная сочетаемость: души усопших.* - вот тут согласен, неприятие куда меньше. Но! Всё это не по теме. Вопрос-то об отпевании. Церковный канон (канон здесь - правило, предписание) весьма осторожен в рекомендациях.  Отпевают усопших (а не их души), а а душах (заблудших, к примеру) молятся. И никак иначе. То есть с позиций церковного канона, (православного - как минимум) предложенный вариант тоже нельзя назвать удачным в смысле сочетаемости. Но я совсем не уверен, что этот подход можно перенести на бытовой уровень.

Comment: Тем более непонятно, насколько всё это применимо на бытовом уровне в отношении авторской конструкции. Вот, собственно и все - о моих сомнениях.

Comment: *Корректно все-таки – это души усопших.* - То есть "отпевание душ усопших" - корректно? Брррр....

Comment: Вот "молитва об упокоении души усопшего" - я бы еще пропустил - но только в силу полного своего неведения... Слух не режет - но не более. Потому как избыточностью попахивает. Даже тавтологичностью... Но повторюсь - не знаю.

Comment: Посмотрела сочетаемость для "отпевание". Кажется там отпевают самих усопших, а не их души  https://kartaslov.ru/сочетаемость-слова/отпевание  "Когда он умер, церемония отпевания усопшего в церкви длилась более трёх часов – так много людей захотело поделиться воспоминаниями об удивительной доброте этого человека.
Гэри Чепмен, Любовь как образ жизни, 2008

Answer (score 3):

**Я думаю, с некоторой натяжкой можно.**

Седьмое значение "души" по БТС:

> *Разг.* Человек (обычно при указании количества). Кругом ни души
> (никого). Не узнает ни одна д. (никто). Досталось (пришлось) чего-л.
> на душу (в расчёте на одного или каждого человека). Потребление
> продуктов на душу населения (в расчёте на одного потребителя). Все как
> одна д. (все как один).

P. S. "Мёртвые души" — это, я так понимаю, не столько абсурд, сколько использование "души" в восьмом значении по БТС:

> В России до реформы 1861 г.: крепостной крестьянин. Имение в три
> тысячи душ. Двести душ дворовых.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135404/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid---).